# Upgrade Sitecore Managed Cloud Containers from AKS 1.23 to 1.24

Tags: sitecore-managed-cloud, aks

AKS will [deprecate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/supported-kubernetes-versions?tabs=azure-cli#aks-kubernetes-release-calendar) Kubernetes version 1.23 on April 2nd 2023. Customers whose Sitecore Managed cloud solution based on the older AKS cluster version(1.23 or older) will face issues maintaining their environments. After April 2nd 2023, customers running version 1.23* will not be able to:

- Scale their AKS nodes
- Manipulation of AKS and VM infrastructure

Is there any detailed documentation pertaining to the steps required to upgrade the package versions and the AKS cluster version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Upgrade Instructions**

1. Download an upgrade package for the required topology and version from the [storage](https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_Azure_Storage/ContainerMenuBlade/%7E/overview/storageAccountId/%2Fsubscriptions%2F06841065-b1ff-4f84-bf1c-f13d07c59810%2FresourceGroups%2Fmcc-shared-upgrade-storage-rg%2Fproviders%2FMicrosoft.Storage%2FstorageAccounts%2Fmccsharedupgradestorage/path/mcc-upgrades/etag/%220x8D9468AF8C2CD36%22/defaultEncryptionScope/%24account-encryption-key/denyEncryptionScopeOverride%7E/false/defaultId//publicAccessVal/None). There is a list of available upgrade packages:

**Sitecore 10.1.0:**

- mcc.xp.upgrade.10.1.0-r.0.1.287527.nupkg
- mcc.xm.upgrade.10.1.0-r.0.1.287527.nupkg
- mcc.xc.upgrade.10.1.0-r.0.1.287527.nupkg

**Sitecore 10.1.1:**

- mcc.xp.upgrade.10.1.1-r.0.1.287525.nupkg
- mcc.xm.upgrade.10.1.1-r.0.1.287525.nupkg

**Sitecore 10.1.2:**

- mcc.xp.upgrade.10.1.2-r.0.1.287524.nupkg
- mcc.xm.upgrade.10.1.2-r.0.1.287524.nupkg

**Sitecore 10.2.0:**

- mcc.xp.upgrade.10.2.0-r.0.1.287520.nupkg
- mcc.xm.upgrade.10.2.0-r.0.1.287520.nupkg

2. Install the upgrade package to your solution (follow the guideline for Sitecore [10.1](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/managed-cloud/walkthrough--updating-managed-cloud.html) or Sitecore [10.2](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/102/managed-cloud/walkthrough--updating-managed-cloud.html)).
3. Run the Infrastructure pipeline.
4. Run the Application pipeline.
5. Run the check cluster upgrades pipeline. You will see the message to upgrade the AKS in the logs.
   [image]
6. Run the cluster version upgrade pipeline (Kubernetes_version 1.24 - select the latest available patch version received from the pipeline in step 5).
   [image]
7. Once the above pipelines run successfully, Go to Kubernetes service on Azure Portal and check the AKS version
   [image]

**Note:** Upgrade your solution only if the version you have is earlier than the ones listed below in the Solution section. To find out the version of your solution, view the `solution.json` file in the *infrastructure* repository of your Sitecore Managed Cloud Containers Azure DevOps project. If your environment is still running on AKS 1.22, it is recommended first to upgrade to AKS 1.23 and then follow the above steps.